# Random interpolation between 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a way to make a random interpolation between two numpy arrays with few "magical" Numpy operations as possible.

for example, having

a =[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

i would like to have as output

c = [ between 1 and 4, between 2 and 5, between 3,6] of integers.

means sort of

```
def mate_interpolate(arr,arr2):
'''
takes 2 parents of same dimention
created a child array of same dimention 
on each place having the element, what value is randomly uniform between
the values of parents 
       '''    

randfloats = np.random.uniform(0,1,arr.shape)
child =  arr2 - arr
child *= randfloats
child += arr
#print(randfloats)
#child = arr + (arr2 - arr) * randfloats
return child
```

but without creating this additional array and/or with only integers.

Comment: If you want to avoid temporary arrays, you can always process the elements individually. You can write the code in cython or pre-compile with numba for similar or likely even better performance.

Comment: What's the matter with `(arr2 - arr)*np.random.rand(*arr.shape) + arr`?

Comment: @Ivan. I count three temp arrays

Comment: Ok, if that's what OP means by *magical*...

Comment: i want to have ints because it should be faster and no convertion back to ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For floats, you can just do:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
result = rng.uniform(a, b)
```

If you want integers, you can either truncate, or if `b > a`:

```
result = rng.integers(a, b, endpoint=True)
```

Comment: @Smer5. Do you know what interpolation is?

Comment: in this situation it is jsut called that, suggest better name

Comment: @Smer5. Selecting random numbers in multiple ranges?

Comment: yes, i do not want to discuss the term, it is just your code does not make the task shown above

Comment: @Smer5. How so? Did you need `endpoint=True` in the second case for inclusive bounds?

Comment: you do not get that i do not want simple uniform integer distribution, i want random values between each value in arrays

Comment: @Smer5. Can you post an example of where my code does not do that? The inputs are the high and low bounds for each point in the array. Is that not what you mean by interpolation?